# ¿como puedo hacer que el editor no tome como comentario la barra lateral " \ "?

Tags: javascript

Necesito hacer una función que cambie una sección de una ruta de archivo.

ej = C:\Users\ **frand** \Desktop\CATALOGO\bayer\1.png ===> C:\Users\ **santi** \Desktop\CATALOGO\bayer\1.png

pero lo que sucede es que me elimina las barras laterales y la primer letra siguiente. esto concluye en que el resultado no es el deseado

```
function cambiarRuta(str=''){

let newStr = str.replace('frand','santi')

console.log(newStr)
  
}  
 
recortarstring('C:\Users\frand\Desktop\CATALOGO\bayer\1.png')
```

Resultado= 'C:UsersrandDesktopCATALOGOayer.png'

esperado = C:\Users\santi\Desktop\CATALOGO\bayer\1.png

Agradecería mucho su ayuda!

Comment: escapa cada \ con una doble \\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba colocando las barras entre comillas dobles (si para el string utilizas comillas simples, sino al revés).

Answer (score 0):

```
    function cambiarRuta(str) {
  let newStr = str.replace("frand", "santi");

  console.log(newStr);
}

let str = `C:Users/frand/Desktop/CATALOGO/bayer/1.png`;
```

cambiando "" por "/" me funciono perfectamente